# Angular Nested-Form builder giving "Cannot find control with path" error

Tags: angular, nested-forms, formbuilder, angular-formbuilder

I have an Angular nested Form which is divided into Tabs, and each tab has multiple input elements as in [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pr13ls) stackblitz.

Please help me resolve below issue:

```
Error: Cannot find control with path: 'averageBos -> sip5xx -> SIP500 -> avg'
```

Comment: I just tried your stackblitz example and didn't get any errors... What is the scenario when you get this error?

Comment: @miselking Please check this stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pr13ls

Comment: There are no controls named `avg` and `avg1`. They are called `critical` and `warning`. Therefore, just rename in `html` file to _critical_ and _warning_ (or the other way around)...

Comment: ``formControlName`` is used for ``input`` tag and not for a ``div``

Comment: @user3331232 Seems that both of the links you have provided don't have errors in them. Could you please add your original html in the post, so that others can see what was wrong before the fix. I can see that you are correctly using "`formGroupName` for a div tag and `formControlName` for an input tag" as pointed out by @HDJEMAI

Comment: No, that was not the case in his original template, I corrected that, but may be me or him, has mistakenly corrected the template where he should keep it as is, as a proof that it wasn't working. before in place of ``critical`` it was ``arg`` if I remember well, I'm not able to find the original stackblitz for now

Answer (score 1):

I've corrected your errors:

use `formGroupName` for a `div` tag and `formControlName` for an `input` tag

```
<my-tabs>
  <my-tab [tabTitle]="'Tab 1'">
    <form [formGroup]="MyGroup">
      <label>Average MOS</label>
      <div formGroupName="averageMos">
        <input type="text" formControlName="critical">
      </div>
    </form>
  </my-tab>
  <my-tab tabTitle="Tab 2">
    <form [formGroup]="MyGroup">
      <label>Average BOS</label>
   <div formGroupName="averageBos">
     <div formGroupName="sip5xx">
       <div formGroupName="SIP500">
         <input type="text" formControlName="critical">
         <input type="text" formControlName="warning">
       </div>
     <div formGroupName="SIP501">
       <input type="text" formControlName="critical">
       <input type="text" formControlName="warning">
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
     </form>
  </my-tab>

 </my-tabs>
```

Try [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kywikv?file=src/app/app.component.html) demo.

if you want to do: `formControlName="avg"` then you have to find that control in the class file.

Comment: @user3331232: can you confirm if this works for you ?